# jersey just display letter ‘GET’

Tags: java, jersey

I use jersey in my project to implement RESTful service. After I type the url my browser displays only the characters 'GET'. I dont know where it is wrong.

Here is the `web.xml`:

```xml
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>
  com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer
</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.bcom.restful.server.sequence</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/restfulService/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Here is the resource class:

```java
@Path("/tenant/{tId}/seqContinue/{sName}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class SequenceContinueService {

    private ISequenceGenerator sequenceGenerator;

    @GET
    public Sequence getSequenceContinue(@PathParam("tId") String tenantId,
            @PathParam("sName") String seqName) {

        if (!hasParams()) {

            try {
                Sequence seq = new Sequence();
                  seq.setSeqenceStr(Convert
                        .toString(sequenceGenerator.nextSequence(seqName))) ;
                  return seq;
            } catch (ApplicationException e) {
                ResponseBuilder builder = Response
                        .status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                builder.type("application/json");
                builder.entity(e.getMessage());
                throw new WebApplicationException(builder.build());

            }

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Browser just displays the characters 'GET' on the screen.

Comment: What URL to you try in the browser? Can `Sequence` be formated as JSON?

Comment: Did you try to debug the service, to know at least that the right web service method is actually called? You could also extend your question with the environment details (API versions, application server).

Answer (score 0):

If you want [JSON support with Jersey 1.*](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.18/json.html), you have to add this `init-param` to your servlet configuration:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

You might have to extend the following too, to get Jersey detect JSON provider classes:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.bcom.restful.server.sequence;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Other material on the same topic:

- [Mkyong's Jersey + Jackson example](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/json-example-with-jersey-jackson/)
- [Jersey 2.0 equivalent to POJOMappingFeature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568469/jersey-2-0-equivalent-to-pojomappingfeature)