# no injection source found error when using multiple @PathParams in Restful Resource using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I am working on a simple Restful web service using Rest / Jersey with Tomcat 7.  Things are working just fine if all of my Paths include a single parameter.  If I include one that uses more than one parameter, I encounter the "No injection source found" error when I try to hit any of the resource paths supported by my resource class - even those that were working before.  If I comment out that particular piece of code, all of my other paths work as expected.  But if I uncomment out that piece of code, I cannot use ANY of the my paths.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

// get all the information about a specific item
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getItem(@PathParam("id") String itemId)
{
    String answer = "{";
    answer += "\"itemid\":\"" + itemId + "\",";
    answer += "\"type\":0,";
    answer += "\"sector\":322948,";
    answer += "\"created\":53249098220";
    answer += "}";

    return answer;
}

// if I comment out this method, all is fine; 
// if I leave it in, error is thrown when I make any restful call
// query to see if there is a new item for user
@Path("/loc/{userid}/{xloc}/{yloc}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String getNewitem(@PathParam("userid") String userId,
    @PathParam("xloc") Number xLoc,
    @PathParam("yloc") Number yLoc)
{
    String answer = "{\"itemid\":\"abcdefgh\"}";
    return answer;
}
```

Here is the error trace:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.

[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public java.lang.String com.drunkware.geobijous.resources.GBBijouResource.getNewBijou(java.lang.String,java.lang.Number,java.lang.Number) at index 1.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=GET, consumedTypes=[], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.drunkware.geobijous.resources.GBBijouResource, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@757bdd3c]}, definitionMethod=public java.lang.String com.drunkware.geobijous.resources.GBBijouResource.getNewBijou(java.lang.String,java.lang.Number,java.lang.Number), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=userid, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Number, source=latitude, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Number, source=longitude, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class java.lang.String}, nameBindings=[]}']
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:467)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:163)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:323)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:320)
        org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
        org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
        javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestions to get around this problem? I am using jersey 2.12. Is this a known bug?

Comment: Should you have an `@GET` annotation for the second function?

Answer (score 6):

The injection error you receive is caused by `Number` parameters. Since complex objects like Number are not supported in @PathParam implementation. You could easily fix this by the following code (also add the @GET)

```
@GET
@Path("loc/{userid}/{xloc}/{yloc}")
public String getNewitem(@PathParam("userid") String userId,
    @PathParam("xloc") int xLoc,
    @PathParam("yloc") int yLoc)
{
    String answer = "{\"itemid\":\"abcdefgh\"}";
    return answer;
}
```

There are many ways to work with complex objects in case you need more information than `int` can provide you. But then you must change the way to receive them since `@PathParam` is quite simple.
For more details regarding complex usage, check [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) to help you with object/json conversion. You probably will have something like this:

```
@POST
@Path("loc/{userid}")
public String createNewitem(@PathParam("userid") String userId, MyLocalization aLoc)
{
    String answer = "{\"itemid\":\"abcdefgh\"}";
    return answer;
}
```

The class `MyLocalization` is a pojo that you will create to be handled by jackson libs with following [dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568469/jersey-2-0-equivalent-to-pojomappingfeature):

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
  </dependency>
```