# AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.sun.jersey.api.uri.UriBuilderImpl...resolved method 'abstract javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder

Tags: java, rest, jackson, jersey, jax-rs

I'm seeing the following error in my stacktrace:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class com.sun.jersey.api.uri.UriBuilderImpl 
does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract 
javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder uri(java.lang.String)' of abstract class javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.
```

The app code was compiled with Jersey 1.19 and Jackson 1.9.2 and for use on Apache Tomcat 7.x. The code was moved over to Apache Tomcat 9.x without recompilation. I am seeing newer versions of Jackson deployed  to Tomcat 9.x, which means there are other applications which are dependent on said new version. Jackson 2.1.0. And I also see jakarata.ws.rs-api-2.1.5.

I want to avoid having to upgrade the app code to a Jersey 2.x because that will involve updating the code which could take a bit of time. It is just for this UriBuilder class. Is there some way to make the app continue to work with Jersey 1.19 and appease this error?

I already checked [AbstractMethodError using UriBuilder on JAX-RS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30176811/abstractmethoderror-using-uribuilder-on-jax-rs)
and
[Jersey 2.0 equivalent to POJOMappingFeature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568469/jersey-2-0-equivalent-to-pojomappingfeature)
and the web.xml changes specified didn't help. From what the instructions say, it appears I do have the recompile the app code but only need to update javax.ws.rs to 2.x and can leave jersey 1.19 as is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-m12</version>
</dependency>
```

Is that right? If not, what can I do to ensure I can keep using Jersey 1.19 and avoid code changes?

Comment: See [upgrade from 1,x to 2.x guide](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/migration.html#mig-1.x).